# Program for dynamic matrix allocation

Tags: c, matrix

I am learning C. I have a program that dynamically creates and fills two matrices X and Y, with random numbers using rand() as shown below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void main(){

 int i, j, k, m, n;
 double **x;
 double **y;
 printf("Enter a number as the size of two square matrices\n");
 scanf("%d", &m);
 x = (double**)malloc(m * sizeof(double));  
 y = (double**)malloc(m * sizeof(double));
 /* initialize random seed: */
 srand(time(NULL));
 for(i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    x[i] = (double*)malloc(m * sizeof(double));
    y[i] = (double*)malloc(m * sizeof(double));
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            x[i][j] = rand();
            y[i][j] = rand();
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
  }
  printf("\n\n");
}
```

When I run this program and give 2 as size of my matrix, I am seeing "Segmetation Fault" as error. Please note that the idea is to fill the two matrices with random elements of type double. Let me know if the above code is correct.

**Corrected:Edit1**

```
 x = (double**)malloc(m * sizeof(double*)); 
 y = (double**)malloc(m * sizeof(double*));
 /* initialize random seed: */
 srand(time(NULL));
 for(i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    x[i] = (double*)malloc(m * sizeof(double));
    y[i] = (double*)malloc(m * sizeof(double));

    for(j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        x[i][j] = rand();
        y[i][j] = rand();
    }
    printf("\n");

  }
  printf("\n\n");
}
```

Above is working correctly now. Need some explanation on 
 x = (double**)malloc(m * sizeof(double*)); 
 and 
x[i] = (double*)malloc(m * sizeof(double));

why * for sizeof(double*) in x = (double**)malloc(m * sizeof(double*));

**Edit2**

```
void main(){

 int i, j, k, m, n; 
 printf("Enter a number as the size of two square matrices\n");
 scanf("%d", &m);

 double (*x)[m] = malloc(sizeof(double[m][m]));
 double (*y)[m] = malloc(sizeof(double[m][m]));
 /* initialize random seed: */
 srand(time(NULL));
 for(i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        x[i][j] = rand();
        y[i][j] = rand();
    }
    printf("\n");

  }
  printf("\n\n");
}
```

As per Jens Gustedt matrix allocation changed... I have removed

```
 double **x;
 double **y;
 x = (double**)malloc(m * sizeof(double*)); 
 y = (double**)malloc(m * sizeof(double*));
 x[i] = (double*)malloc(m * sizeof(double));
 y[i] = (double*)malloc(m * sizeof(double));
```

Comment: No it's not correct. Getting a seg fault clearly tells you there's a problem. Suggest you run your program in a debugger and/or add debugging print statements to try to find your problem. Also you may want to look at the "Related" links in this question. This type of matrix allocation has been asked many times already.

Comment: user3121023 thanks for pointing out. I have added * and removed inner i loop.

Comment: @user3121023 can you explain the lines 
    x = (double**)malloc(m * sizeof(double)); and   x[i] = (double*)malloc(m * sizeof(double));

Comment: These are only fake matrices and this technique belongs into a museum. In modern C, since C99, simply allocate a 2D matrix as `double (*matrix)[m] = malloc(sizeof(double[m][m]));`. So you only need one call to `malloc` for the whole matrix and have it all in consecutive memory.

Comment: also you no should forget about free.

Comment: @user3121023 thanks for the explanation and your time

Comment: @JensGustedt I am going to make a edit  in few minutes to the code above as per your suggestion. Please let me know if it is correct

Comment: @JensGustedt Please let me know if the above Edit2 is what you mean

Comment: Yes, looks much nicer, doesn't it?

Comment: @JensGustedt Yes it does..Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These are only fake matrices and this technique belongs into a museum. In modern C, since C99, simply allocate a 2D matrix as `double (*matrix)[m] = malloc(sizeof(double[m][m]));`. So you only need one call to `malloc` for the whole matrix and have it all in consecutive memory.
– Jens Gustedt